# Email clustering using numpy and pandas

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to cluster my raw email data using numpy and pandas only.

Hence Im Trying to create an email dataframe from raw emails that I have. However the issue that I have is that I keep getting an AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'message'.

I dont know where Im going wrong with my code

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def parse_raw_message(raw_message):
    lines = raw_message.split('\n')
    email = {}
    message = ''
    keys_to_extract = ['from', 'to']
    for line in lines:
        if ':' not in line:
            message += line.strip()
            email['body'] = message
        else:
            pairs = line.split(':')
            key = pairs[0].lower()
            val = pairs[1].strip()
            if key in keys_to_extract:
                email[key] = val
    return email


def parse_into_emails(messages):
    emails = [parse_raw_message(message) for message in messages]
    return {
        'body': map_to_list(emails, 'body'), 
        'to': map_to_list(emails, 'to'), 
        'from_': map_to_list(emails, 'from')
    }


email_df = pd.DataFrame(parse_into_emails(emails.message))
```

---

---

```
AttributeError           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-df1de00c07ed> in <module>
----> 1 email_df = pd.DataFrame(parse_into_emails(emails.message))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, 
name)
   5065             if 
self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'message'
```

---

Comment: Check the column names of your _email_ variable. It is complaining that message is not there.